# Apache2 - Images & CSS only available w/in local network, not via TLD

Tags: debian, dns, apache-http-server, ddns

I'm running Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) on a local machine which uses a dynamic DNS service to be accessible from the outside. In general, this works like a charm.

However, the server refuses to load both images and CSS if you were to connect via the TLD provided by the DNS-service (e.g. "subdomain.dns.com"). If you connect from w/in the network (VPN, e.g. "10.8.x.x"), everything displays as it should. This applies for simple test-scenarios like a straightforward `<img src="/images/test.png" />` w/in the standard `index.html` as well as for complex systems like roundcubemail or ownCloud (which look really messed up w/o the styling).

The `/etc/apache2/sitse-available/default` file is configured as

```
<VirtualHost *:80> #apparently, this isn't the complete file
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

And the `etc/apache2/ports.conf` as

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80 #same for 443
```

I really have no clue what's going on here. My .htaccess-configuration **doesn't** limit the access to a certain IP-range, the `.htaccess` for the /images-subfolder used in the example above even is configured as:

```
Satisfy Any
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

Even w/ chmod 777 set, the image doesn't load via TLD-access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by AdBlock. AdBlock recognized the DDNS-subdomain as Ad-Server, hence blocking almost everything. Since I use my own TLD everything works fine again. So, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code for the page itself (where it loads the CSS file).  It may be hard-coded to point at the internal address or IP.  It's the browser that loads the CSS file, not the server.